# Mapping MongoDB documents to case class with types but without embedded documents

Tags: scala, mongodb, subset, salat

[Subset](https://github.com/osinka/subset) looks like an interesting, thin MongoDB wrapper.

In one of the examples given, there are Tweets and Users. However, `User` is a *subdocument* of `Tweet`. In  classical SQL, this would be normalized into two separate tables with a foreign key from Tweet to User. In MongoDB, this wouldn't necessitate a `DBRef`, storing the user's `ObjectId` would be sufficient.

Both in Subset and Salat this would result in these case classes:

```
case class Tweet(_id: ObjectId, content: String, userId: ObjectId)
case class User(_id: ObjectId, name: String)
```

So there's no guarantee that the ObjectId in Tweet actually resolves to a User (making it less typesafe). I also have to write the same query for each class that references User (or move it to some trait).

So what I'd like to achieve is to have `case class Tweet(_id: ObjectId, content: String, userId: User)`, in code, and the `ObjectId` in the database. Is this possible, and if so, how? What are good alternatives?

Comment: In Salat they have child collections, which kind of solve the problem, but not fully.

Comment: well if you want relations, shouldn't you be using a RDBMS instead ? I would have used sub documents in this case...

Comment: Certainly you will not be able to set query conditions on referred object (vs. SQL "join"). But still you may want to store an entity in its own collection and refer to it from other objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Actually it's even simpler than having a "user" sub-document in a "tweet". When "user" is a reference, it is just a scalar value, MongoDB and "Subset" has no mechanisms to query subdocument fields.

I've prepared a simple REPLable snippet of code for you (it assumes you have two collections -- "tweets" and "users").

Preparations...

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId
import com.mongodb._
import com.osinka.subset._
import Document.DocumentId

val db = new Mongo("localhost") getDB "test"
val tweets = db getCollection "tweets"
val users = db getCollection "users"
```

Our `User` case class

```
case class User(_id: ObjectId, name: String)
```

A number of fields for tweets and user

```
val content = "content".fieldOf[String]
val user = "user".fieldOf[User]
val name = "name".fieldOf[String]
```

---

Here more complicated things start to happen. What we need is a `ValueReader` that's capable of getting `ObjectId` based on field name, but then goes to another collection and reads an object from there.

This can be written as a single piece of code, that does all things at once (you may see such a variant in the answer history), but it would be more idiomatic to express it as a combination of readers. Suppose we have a `ValueReader[User]` that reads from `DBObject`:

```
val userFromDBObject = ValueReader({
  case DocumentId(id) ~ name(name) => User(id, name)
})
```

What's left is a generic `ValueReader[T]` that expects `ObjectId` and retrieves an object from a specific collection using supplied underlying reader:

```
class RefReader[T](val collection: DBCollection, val underlying: ValueReader[T]) extends ValueReader[T] {
  override def unpack(o: Any):Option[T] =
    o match {
      case id: ObjectId =>
        Option(collection findOne id) flatMap {underlying.unpack _}
      case _ =>
        None
    }
}
```

Then, we may say our type class for reading `User`s from references is merely

```
implicit val userReader = new RefReader[User](users, userFromDBObject)
```

> (I am grateful to you for this question, since this use case is quite
>   rare and I had no real motivation to develop a generic solution. I think
>   I need to include this kind of helper into "Subset" finally..
>   I shall appreciate your feedback on this approach)

---

And this is how you would use it:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._

tweets.find.iterator.asScala foreach { 
  case Document.DocumentId(id) ~ content(content) ~ user(u) =>
    println("%s - %s by %s".format(id, content, u))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't tried out your generic solution yet, but the other one works well. One other area of improvement would be to use Casbah instead of the Java driver.

Comment: I'm not experienced in Casbah and tried to design Subset to be driver-agnostic. I believe using Casbah for such a simple example is overkill, since only a couple of methods is required from a driver. Anyway I would love to see if someone posted experience on using Subset+Casbah

Comment: For example I use `tweets.find(MongoDBObject("user" -> aUser._id))` because my ValueWriter doesn't work yet.

Comment: You do not need a `ValueWriter` here, you may define another field (`"user".fieldOf[ObjectId]`) or simply write `tweets.find("user".fieldOf[Object] -> aUser._id)` or `tweets.find("user".fieldOf[Object](aUser._id))`

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention, if you have `user` field of type `User`, you may call `user.as[ObjectId]` to convert it to `Field[ObjectId]`. So that `user.as[ObjectId] === aUser._id` should work too.

Comment: Perfect! I've assembled a [small Play project](https://github.com/mariussoutier/subset-play-demo), trying to imagine how I would use this in a real app. I will add some code throughout the next few days...

Comment: Nothing against Subset, but this seems a lot of code for something simple to solve...

Answer (score 0):

Alexander Azarov answer works probably fine, but I would personally not do it this way.

What you have is a Tweet that only have an ObjectId reference to the user.
And you want to load the user during tweet load because for your domain it is probably easier to manipulate. In any case, unless you use subdocuments (not always a good choice), you have to query the DB again to retrieve the user data, and this is what is done by Alexander Azarov.

You would rather do a transformation function that transforms a Tweet to a TweetWithUser or something like that.

```
  def transform(tweet: Tweet) = TweetWithUser( tweet.id, tweet.content, findUserWithId(tweet.userId) )
```

**I don't really see why you would expect a framework to resolve something that you could have done yourself very easily in a single line of code.**

And remember in your application, in some cases you don't even need the whole User object, so it is expensive to query twice the database while it's not always needed. You should only use the case class with the full User data when you really need that user data, and not simply always load the full user data because it seems more convenient.

Or if you want to manipulate User objects anyway, you would have a User proxy, on which you could access the id attribute directly, and on any other access, a db query would be done. In Java/SQL, Hibernate is doing with lazy loading of relationships, but I'm not sure it's a good idea to use that with MongoDB and it breaks immutability